# How can I see a view of all unique fields for an Object?

Tags: custom-field, standard-objects, fields, custom-object

I can see all of the fields listed on the Object page, but there is no column that indicates which fields have been checked as unique.

How can I see what all of the unique fields are for an Object?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schema builder opening might help .Schema builder identifies unique fields.thanks

You can find this in the list of fields. [Link](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000h0l5AAA)